# What's stackoverflow.co.nz site up too?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

So 10% of the time when I go to type stackoverflow.com I actually type stackoverflow.co.nz because .co.nz is my local ccTLD. Force of habit if I've been surfing locally. I normally don't get as far as hitting enter but tonight I did.

If I do this in IE, I get a dialog box asking me if I want to allow the website to open a program on my computer. Obviously I clicked "Hell No" in response to that.

But when I pulled out my sniffer I couldn't find anything. The site just seems to recursively redirect to itself and with each iteration it appends a /stackoverflow.com to the url as below:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.co.nz/stackoverflow.com/[etc etc]stackoverflow.com/
```

So is there actually anything nasty there or is this just IE being alarmist? Firefox & Chrome shrug it off with an eventual BAD REQUEST 400. But I wondered, what's this site up too?

Something mindless or something sinister?

Comment: Not sure this is really a "meta" topic, though. It doesn't really concern the SO family, only another site, if I understood good.

Comment: First it adds one. Then two. Then four. Then eight. And so on and so forth and so long.

Comment: @random: and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: we tried to warn you but oh deaaaaarrr (8)

Comment: I need me a copy of IE that has the Hell No button

Comment: @squillman: http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of [buffer overflow vulnerabilities](http://www.google.com/search?q=long+url+buffer+overflow+internet+explorer+site%3Amicrosoft.com) in various versions of Internet Explorer. It seems this site is trying to demonstrate some of those.

It looks like their registration is going to expire in 10 days.

Comment: +1 either that, or an innocent redirection gone wrong. Howeve, the use of ".com" points against that.

Comment: So stackoverflow.co.nz is just trying to stack overflow

Comment: Yup, but I dont know why the Urls are being incremented. Why not just go from 0 to 100 in one step? Why redirect 8-9 times?

Comment: @rism Maybe he is trying to take advantage of http://osvdb.org/30834